# how to make all images in cardviews have fixed size?

Tags: android, android-cardview

I want to make all images that are in cardviews have a fixed size, not like these images have different sizes in the cardview. I need to make the image above the divider line.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So. You can make (res -> values -> dimens.xml).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="testHeight">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="testWidth">30dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And give it for your ImageView. All of your image.
If you need addjust height you can add **android:adjustViewBounds="true"** whith **android:layout_height="wrap_content"**

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/testWidth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/testHeight"
        android:src="@drawable/noise"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```